# removing a string pattern in .xls

Tags: string, excel, removeall

I have a .xls that has 2 columns.

```
Column A          Column B 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Great       |     Great English Muffins 
Sphinx      |  Sphinx Cranberry Muffins 
Top Measure |    Top Measure Chardonnay
```

Question :

How can I get the below output using Excel formula/functions as in Column C ?

```
Column A          Column B                      Column C 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Great       |     Great English Muffins -->  English Muffins
Sphinx      |  Sphinx Cranberry Muffins -->  Cranberry Muffins
Top Measure |    Top Measure Chardonnay -->  Chardonnay
```

Column A may be more than 1 word and I want to run this function on a .xls with ~2000 rows of data.

Any detailed help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `SUBSTITUTE` function.

Comment: =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2, ""))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function in combination with the [TRIM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9) function, as dbugger writes in his comment.
But you have to add a 1 as 4th parameter, so that you substitute only the first occurrence;

```
  |  Column A   |         Column B          |            Column C            |
--+-------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------+
1 | Great       |     Great English Muffins | =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1, "",1)) |
2 | Sphinx      |  Sphinx Cranberry Muffins | =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B2,A2, "",1)) |
3 | Top Measure |    Top Measure Chardonnay | =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B3,A3, "",1)) |
...
```